# Separating Dates in Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, python-datetime

I am trying to do forecasting on a data using dates. The problem is i have a dataset like this

```
    LeaveStartDate  TotalLeaveDays
0   2020-03-14  1.0
1   2020-03-18  2.0
2   2020-03-20  1.0
3   2020-01-13  3.0
4   2020-02-15  1.0
```

I want to expand total leaves like:

```
  LeaveStartDate   TotalLeaveDays

    0  2020-03-14       1.0

    1   2020-03-18      1.0

    2   2020-03-19      1.0

    3   2020-01-20      1.0

    4   2020-01-13      1.0

    5   2020-01-14      1.0

    6   2020-01-15      1.0

    7   2020-02-15      1.0
```

what should i do to get this form of data

Comment: are you sure your expected output is correct?

Comment: i corrected my output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Index.repeat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) by column `TotalLeaveDays`, then add counter values converted to days timedeltas by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) and [`to_timedelta`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_timedelta.html) and last set `1` to `TotalLeaveDays` column:

```
df['LeaveStartDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['LeaveStartDate'])

df = df.loc[df.index.repeat(df['TotalLeaveDays'])]
df['LeaveStartDate'] += pd.to_timedelta(df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='D')
df['TotalLeaveDays'] = 1
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
print (df)
  LeaveStartDate  TotalLeaveDays
0     2020-03-14               1
1     2020-03-18               1
2     2020-03-19               1
3     2020-03-19               1
4     2020-03-20               1
5     2020-03-21               1
6     2020-01-13               1
7     2020-02-17               1
```

Comment: i tried this but this error occurred AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_datetime'

Comment: @MuhammadIrtiza - Do you use `pd.to_datetime`, not `df.to_datetime` ?

Comment: yup i used df.to_datetime. my bad now it workf perfect. thankyou so much